# “No valid partition table was found on this device.” + “Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!” + fdisk reads “7.3T” Size; How do I fix this?

Tags: debian, ext4, partition-recovery, fdisk, parted

Distro: Netrunner Blackbird (Debian)

I/O: Sata to USB cable

***KDE Parition Editor:*** "No valid partition table was found on this device."

```
me@computer:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA LITEONIT LCT-128 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  269MB   268MB   primary  ext4         boot
 2      269MB   32.5GB  32.2GB  primary  ext4
 3      32.5GB  54.0GB  21.5GB  primary  ext4
 4      54.0GB  128GB   74.1GB  primary  ext4


Model: ATA ST1000LM049-2GH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  8591MB  8590MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 2      8591MB  17.2GB  8590MB  primary  ext4
 3      17.2GB  1000GB  983GB   primary  ext4


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel? i
Model: WDC WD10 02F9YZ-09H1JL1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      8389kB  8002GB  8002GB  primary
```

...

```
me@computer:~$ sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 244190646 sectors
Disk model: 02F9YZ-09H1JL1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x45b0734a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953523711 1953521664  7.3T 83 Linux
```

...

This:

```
me@computer:~$ sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdc > sdc-backup.txt
```

Gave me this as a text file in my home folder:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x45b0734a
device: /dev/sdc
unit: sectors

/dev/sdc1 : start=        2048, size=  1953521664, type=83
```

...

So, I'm not sure as to what exactly is going on here or how to fix it... I looked up the `sudo parted` error and found this:

https://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php

Looks to be the same issue (and it seems that finding this with gparted, instead of KDE's Partition Editor is irrelevant), but before I go making changes to a partition table, I want to be as careful as possible, because I REALLY can't lose the data on the HDD.

Any suggestions or know any specific fixes anyone can point me to?

I really appreciate all the help and let me know if you want me to run any other commands to post here.

Thanks all.

FYI: I installed `testdisk` and am running it now, if you need the outputs of that somewhere, let me know.

Comment: Does your BIOS detects the harddisk succesfully? If not, you may need to update your bios to fix it.

Comment: The HDD is connected to the computer through a SATA to USB cable.

Comment: Great, but that really does not answer my question at all. Does the BIOS succesfully detect the harddisk with the right capacity? If not, the problem is at the BIOS.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm BIOS locked right now in my laptop. My laptop does boot to USB first though, but the hard drive does not show up in the boot devices (I also don't have it as a boot device anyway, it was a secondary hard drive I used in Linux to store files only, it never contained an operating system--the entire disk is one single partition, ext4).

Comment: So it does not show up as boot device, which means the BIOS does not detect the drive. I would look into updating the BIOS firmware first.

Comment: Also, other devices do show up in the list of boot devices, when they are plugged into the USB ports, just like this hard drive is. Whether I put flash drives or connect a different internal hard drive to the SATA to USB cable, they show up (I can't boot into them, because they are just storage devices really, but they are there in the boot list).